# Disable spell check on playwright browser

Tags: playwright

I am doing some screenshot comparison. On my machine, in a text box, a word in German gets underlined by the spell check, so the screenshot is taken with the red underline, but on the prod machine, which is located in Germany, it doesn't.

The scenario is that I want to compare screenshots of the edit form. So I select an element and press edit. The element's title is in German, so it gets underlined in the text box when in edit mode.

It is what happens if I open Chrome and in a textbox, like google search, I write a word with no meaning in English. But if I disable the spell check in the browser, like in the screenshot, it won't do it anymore, of course.

But if I disable the spell check in the playwright browser (run the test with opening the browser, then at the end the playwright browser remains open), where the test ran, and run the test again, it resets this setting and underlines it again, this making the screenshot comparison fail.

Is there a way to disable the spell check for the tests? I found that one can set the locale for a specific test, but setting it to de-De doesn't fix it.
[image]